# RecyclerView NullPointerException Issue in getItemCount

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Please look into this and let me know what went wrong.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ItemData[] itemsData;

    public MyAdapter(ItemData[] itemsData) {
        this.itemsData = itemsData;
    }

    public MyAdapter(String[] titles, int[] icons, String name, String email, int profile) {}

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
        View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tab1list, null);
        // create ViewHolder
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        // - get data from your itemsData at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that itemsData
        viewHolder.txtViewTitle.setText(itemsData[position].getTitle());
        viewHolder.imgViewIcon.setImageResource(itemsData[position].getImageUrl());
    }

    // inner class to hold a reference to each item of RecyclerView
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView txtViewTitle;
        public ImageView imgViewIcon;

        public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView);
            txtViewTitle = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.abb);
            imgViewIcon = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.baa);
        }
    }

    // Return the size of your itemsData (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemsData.length;// here im getting the `null` pointer exception error
    }
}
```

Null pointer exception at return itemsData.length; i need to design a listview inside a pager or inside a sliding tablayout. but im getting this error.

Comment: Could you show the constructor for `MyAdapter`? I'm pretty sure you're not passing proper values.

Comment: which constructor is called in your code? Might be the empty one, that would mean `itemsData` is never initialized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `itemsData` parameter passed to the `MyAdapter`'s constructor is null or you are using the second constructor which is not initializes the `itemsData` class member. You can check it for null and return 0 from the `getItemCount` method:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return itemsData == null ? 0 : itemsData.length;
}
```

Comment: In mycase this method gets called sometime/but not regularly after I call finish() in the onPause method() of my activity. ietmcount remains non null before pause but I should be able to make it null in the onPause() and expect that getItemCount() wouldnt be called again because activity is dying..